# How to parse antlr grammar's written in JAVA using C#

Tags: antlr3

Can we able to use antlr grammars (written in java) in visual studio using C#?

I am facing one problem with antlr grammar's that are JAVA target but I want C# target grammars and i couldn't get C# target grammars. So, my question is can we use those antlr JAVA targeted grammars in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Your question title is misleading. ANTLR grammars are written in ANTLR's grammar language, not Java or C#. But I guess your real question is: can we use a parser, generated for the Java target, also with C#. And the obvious answer is: no. The generated code is Java, how can you use that in C#? You have to generate C# code.

Comment: Ok I understood. And I have another question that how to add tokens in Antlr4 grammars.

Comment: As this is  a Q&A site you should not reuse questions for other questions. Instead accept the answer to your first question (if you find it acceptable) and open a new question as outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)